# Why a field $F$ sits naturally inside the ring $F[x]_{m(x)}$ for $m(x)\in F[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomial-rings

I am reading exercise page 231 from Ronald S. Irving's book: Integers, Polynomials and Rings. I can understand and solve problem in part 1. I get ring $\mathbb{F}_2[x]_{x^2}$ is not a field. But, I am stuck in solving part 2 and 3. How can we show that field $F$ sits naturally inside the ring $F[x]_{m(x)}$ for $m(x) \in F[x]$. I appreciate any help. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: That's not the common notation for that, and that's not what that notation commonly means. But they have defined the notation explicitly, so I guess I can work through my confusion. Just be aware of this if you should ever read other algebra texts.

Comment: Each $a$ in $F$ corresponds to an element $a+(m(x))$ in the quotient ring.

Answer (score 0):

There is a natural embedding of of $F$ into $F[x]$. try to show its kernel is exactly $(x)$